# Get Lumetri Settings from 3D LUT

Tags: premiere, lut

I have a few LUT's which I quite like, but a few settings aren't quite what I would like.
I know, that I could simply adjust those settings within the Lumetri Panel, but I would prefere to get the "raw" settings with which the LUTs where created.

Is there a way to get this done in Premiere Pro?

Comment: I know there is at least one program that can create LUTs. I can't recommend any of them personally but have a search for 'lut creator' and see how you go.

Comment: @stib Wrong way, I dont want to create a LIT from the settings, but  Settings from the LIT